# iphone NSString Array

Tags: iphone, arrays, nsstring

I declared

```
NSString    *dayinfield[43];
```

and fill it in

```
-(void)DrawDemo {
dayinfield[2] = @"hallo";
dayinfield[3] = @"test";

// also i can read it
NSLog (@"show: %@",dayinfield[2]);
//works fine
}
```

but when i like to read its content in another function (same class)

```
-(void)ReadData
{
NSLog (@"show: %@",dayinfield[2]);
// I get random infos or “EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

How do I initialize the NSString Array correct so I can reach its content in each of my functions??

Thanks
chris

Comment: Are you sure `-DrawDemo` is called before `-ReadData`?

Comment: Where is `dayinfield` declared by the way - is it really an ivar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only assign literals to the array elements, this should not be a problem. But if you use other strings, you have to retain the instances manually when using a C array.

By the way: Objective-C methods start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: thx remembering about the lowercase.. even did it now :) but my string array prob still exist.  Any short Demo even something else welcomed> I just need a array of nsstrings that I can fill and read from wherever in my class :)

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if you never initialized the array (or the parts of it you are accessing) - if you haven't called `-DrawDemo` before `-ReadData` or used different indices than the ones posted here, the array would simply contain garbage values.

Try to initialize the array contents to `nil` or `@""` in your initializer method and see if the problem persists.

Alternatively consider using a suitable Cocoa container.

Comment: For sure DrawDemo is before ReadData, as mentioned IN DrawDemo I can read the Data perfect, just outside in another function its just deallocated...?? Any short Demo even something else welcomed> I just need a array of nsstrings that I can fill and read from wherever in my class :)

Comment: By the way, the fact that you can read it in `-DrawDemo` but not in `-ReadData` is exactly why i think `-DrawDemo` might not be called first.

Answer (score 0):

It's memory is probably being released before your second call. Assuming you have declared `dayinfield` as an ivar (and the fact that you don't get bad access all the time) your string aren't properly retained.

Initialise the strings like this:

```
dayinfield[2] = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hallo"];
dayinfield[3] = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"test"];
```

and you should release them after you're class is being deallocated (See [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/memorymgmt.html)).

Also, obviously it depends on what you want to do, but it might be easier if you use `NSArray` instead of C arrays.

Comment: @Mo: `var = [@"hello" retain];` is perfectly valid, too.

Comment: String literals don't get deallocated under you (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html)): *"The compiler makes such object constants unique on a per-module basis, and they’re never deallocated, though you can retain and release them as you do any other object."*.

Comment: +1 on some random answer of yours, since I cannot give credit to this comment!

Comment: For sure DrawDemo is before ReadData, as mentioned IN DrawDemo I can read the Data perfect, just outside in another function its just deallocated...?? Any short Demo even something else welcomed> I just need a array of nsstrings that I can fill and read from wherever in my class :)

Comment: I tried also this now in my viewDidLoad
Just to be sure its initialised.

 for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) 
 {
  dayinfield[i] = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@" "];
 }
---
but still the same... i can read it in DrawDemo, but in ReadData its already gone :(

Comment: @Christian: As per the comment above, there is no need to alloc a new string. Those string literal objects ignore release and retain messages.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the OP should work although it is an exercise in sheer masochism to use old school C arrays with objects.

I ran this code:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject {
    NSString *a[1];
}
- (void) drawDemo;
- (void) readData;
@end 

@implementation TestClass

- (void) drawDemo{
    a[0]=@"A Zero";
    a[1]=@"A One";
}//------------------------------------- (void) drawDemo------------------------------------

- (void) readData{
    NSLog(@"a[0]=%@,a[1]=%@",a[0],a[1]);
}//------------------------------------- (void) readData------------------------------------

@end

TestClass *tc=[[TestClass alloc] init];
[tc drawDemo];
[tc readData];
```

... and got this output:

```
a[0]=A Zero,a[1]=A One
```

Your problem is elsewhere in your code. There is no compelling reason to use C arrays with objects. You gain nothing and you have to watch them like a hawk to prevent errors.